# Failed to pass ether from one account to another in truffle with testrpc

Tags: go-ethereum, truffle, testrpc

I have a sample contract with one function:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {

    function sell(address transferTo) public {
        transferTo.transfer(1000);
    }
}
```

I use `testrpc` and `truffle` to deploy and execute contract:

```
Test.deployed().then(instance => instance.sell(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0]}))
```

and command fails with exception on VM level:

```
Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: revert
    at XMLHttpRequest._onHttpResponseEnd (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70604:12)
    at XMLHttpRequest._setReadyState (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70449:12)
    at XMLHttpRequestEventTarget.dispatchEvent (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:70159:18)
    at XMLHttpRequest.request.onreadystatechange (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:315621:13)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:314196:9
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:331156:36
    at Object.InvalidResponse (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/cli.bundled.js:43303:16)
```

Any thoughts what was going wrong? Seems like this function represents what docs says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are calling the `transfer()` method from the contract, it is trying to transfer balance *from the contract itself* rather than taking the 1000 from the caller.  It is failing because the contract has no balance.

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.0;

contract Test {
    function sell(address transferTo)
      public
      payable // make function payable
    {
      // change the amount to the amount sent with the call (msg.value)          
      transferTo.transfer(msg.value);
    }
}
```

In the truffle command, you would have to add a value amount for the transfer:

```
Test.deployed().then(instance => instance.sell(accounts[1], {from: accounts[0], value: web3.toWei(1, 'ether') }))
```

Comment: So what my changes effectively end up doing is just transfer Ether from accounts[0] to accounts[1], which obviously is much easier to do with just directly transferring ether.  But for the pattern above, this would only make sense if there are different functions to get Ether into the contract (payable) and the original function is used to get Ether out of the contract.

Comment: Thank you, I will verify this in 10 minutes. My original contract is more complex, the transfer of ether happens when few conditions met and that's why I need the function itself.

Comment: is there any way to obtain this data dynamically? My business use case is client call the function of contract and function verifies if sender has enough ethereum on the account and take necessary amount

Comment: As far as I am aware, that is not possible. The contract can only control things within the contract, what’s given/paid to it. Seems like a function like you suggest could be quite dangerous, a malicious smart contract creator could exploit someone calling that method if they could access that address’ external balance.  A more typical pattern is people can deposit funds to the contract, the contract keeps account of each address’ funded balance in the contract. Authorized actions could deduct from that balance, and people can withdraw their balances also.

Comment: Actually you could check for things like that in your UI outside of the smart contract itself. For example if you use Metamask, in your UI you specify the amount to deduct from the person’s account. You call the function using web3, which pulls up authorization of that person in Metamask. If their balance is insufficient, that’s handled/rejected by Metamask, before being called on the contract.  This assumes though that it’s the payer who’s initiating the call (their Metamask).

Comment: Thanks! It is first time when I hear about Metamask, initially I planed to use mobile apps